# Virtual box hitting CPU Usage on a machine of configuration of i7-7th gen and 16 GB RAM

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

I am using the configuration of i7-7th gen and 16 GB RAM.
Still if i am using my KALI Linux but still my CPU is hitting 100% usage whenever I am running the OS.

Any Solutions ?

Answer (score -1):

It's a good idea to actually list the top cpu consumers :

```
# ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%cpu| head
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi, CPU utlilization goes high as soon as run my virtual OS.